# Store the file name and location of the saved file to save changes to that specific file? [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx

As I am developing a Text Editor in JavaFX, I need to create a Save menu item option that works like every other editor. I have Opening the file and displaying the text in the file in the TextArea and the Save As options done. It's just the save option that I'm not quite getting.

Main.java:

```
package com.josh.main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.AccessibleRole;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    private BorderPane pane;
    public static TextArea area;
    private Scene scene;
    private MenuBar bar;
    private Menu file;
    private Menu help;

    private MenuItem open;
    private MenuItem save;
    private MenuItem saveAs;
    private MenuItem about;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    private MenuItemEvents events;

    public static Stage primaryStage;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception 
    {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

        setWidth(800);
        setHeight(800);
        initComponents();
        pair();
        pane.setTop(bar);
        pane.setCenter(area);

        about.setOnAction(event -> events.helpItemEvent());
        saveAs.setOnAction(event -> events.saveAsItemEvent());
        open.setOnAction(event -> events.openItemEvent());

        primaryStage.getIcons().add(getIconImage());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("GigaEdit");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) 
    {
        Application.launch(arguments);
    }

    private void initComponents()
    {
        events = new MenuItemEvents();
        pane = new BorderPane();
        area = new TextArea();
        scene = new Scene(pane, getWidth(), getHeight());
        bar = new MenuBar();
        file = new Menu("File");
        help = new Menu("Help");
        open = new MenuItem("Open");
        save = new MenuItem("Save");
        saveAs = new MenuItem("Save As");
        about = new MenuItem("About");

        setAccessibilityRoles();
        setAccessibilityRoleDescriptions();
        setAccessibilityHelp();
    }

    private void setWidth(int width)
    {
        this.width = width;
    }

    private void setHeight(int height)
    {
        this.height = height;
    }

    private int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    private int getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    private void pair()
    {
        bar.getMenus().addAll(file, help);
        file.getItems().addAll(open, save, saveAs);
        help.getItems().add(about);
    }

    private void setAccessibilityRoles()
    {
        bar.setAccessibleRole(AccessibleRole.MENU_BAR);
        area.setAccessibleRole(AccessibleRole.TEXT_AREA);
    }

    private void setAccessibilityRoleDescriptions()
    {
        bar.setAccessibleRoleDescription("Menu Bar. Contains two Menus. First is 'File'. Second is 'Help'");
        area.setAccessibleRoleDescription("Edit Box. This is where you type what you need to type inside of your document.");
    }

    private void setAccessibilityHelp()
    {
        bar.setAccessibleHelp("This Menu Bar contains two Menus. The First is 'File'. The File Menu has your options for opening other files and saving the current file.");
        area.setAccessibleHelp("This text box is used to enter the text that you would like to be in the current document.");
    }

    private Image getIconImage()
    {
        return new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("icon.png"));
    }
}
```

MenuItemEvents.java:

```
package com.josh.main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

public class MenuItemEvents 
{
    public void helpItemEvent()
    {
        HelpAlert.display("About GigaEdit", "GigaEdit v1.0\nCopyright Josh Root 2016\nAny redistribution of this software without proper permission is prohibited\nAny attempt to do such actions will result in legal action taken upon the offender");
    }

    public void openItemEvent()
    {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();

        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt");
        fc.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
        File file = fc.showOpenDialog(Main.primaryStage);
        if(file != null)
        {
            Main.area.setText(readFile(file));
        }
    }

    public void saveItemEvent(){}

    public void saveAsItemEvent()
    {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt");
        fc.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);
        File file = fc.showSaveDialog(Main.primaryStage);

        if(file != null)
        {
            saveFile(Main.area.getText(), file);
        }
    }

    private void saveFile(String text, File file) 
    {
        try
        {
            FileWriter fw;
            fw = new FileWriter(file);
            fw.write(text);
            fw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuItemEvents.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
    private String readFile(File file) 
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try
        {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String text;
            while((text = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuffer.append(text);
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuItemEvents.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MenuItemEvents.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Logger.getLogger(MenuItemEvents.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, have a File instance variable called saveFile,and set it to `null`. The save method should then look like this

```
public void saveItemEvent(){
    if(saveFile == null){
        saveAsItemEvent();
    }else{
        saveFile(Main.area.getText(), saveFile);
    }
}
```

In your saveAsItemEvent, when the user successfully chooses a File, set `saveFile` to that File.

```
saveFileName = file;
```

This is for saving. In your openItemEvent, when the user successfully chooses a File, you can also set `saveFile` to that File, so that when a user opens a file, it will automatically start saving to that file as well.

Comment: Why would you use a `String` instead of a `File` though?

Comment: @James_D The only reason is that Files cannot be serialized, so if he ever attempts to serialize the Object with the File in it, he won't go through hours of trying to figure out that Files cannot be serialized (this is what I went through when I first did a Text Editing Program). Other than that, there really is no reason for using a String rather than a File.

Comment: [`File` is `Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html). While it works, continually converting between strings and file just adds verbosity to the code and seems pretty unnecessary.

Comment: @James_D Huh, I for some reason assumed they weren't. That's strange... Well, I'll edit my answer and change it to Files rather than Strings. Thanks for catch!

Answer (score 0):

The File created in openItemEvent() should be an instance variable instead of a local variable to that method. Then the saveItemEvent() method just calls saveFile(), passing that File instance.